# How do I find all files categorized movies on my disk?

Tags: storage, file, movie

In the dialog of "About this Mac", started from below the Apple menu item, the Storage 'tab' says there are 42.43 GB of Movies.

Ok, how do I find all those files that the system categorizes as movies?

In other words - how did OSX find them?

I can't find them anywhere.

Is there a Terminal ls -al | grep [something] that I can fire off from the root folder to help me find them?

Comment: Just to let you know, even though different variants do seem to work, I changed the `mdfind` command line format to that which is shown in it's [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdfind.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/mdfind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Terminal, use the following command:

```
mdfind "kMDItemKind == '*movie'"
```

This will output the fully qualified pathnames of files in which the metadata stores used by Spotlight classify it as some type of movie.

Example output from a movie taken on my iPhone and transferred to iPhotos on my Mac, one of the lines outputted by [`mdls`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdls.1.html) is:

`kMDItemKind                    = "QuickTime movie"`

"QuickTime movie", which have a `.mov` extension was just one of extension types that showed as "$some_type_of movie". So you will probably see other file extensions as well.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the command line is Spotlight UI itself:

a Spotlight search in Finder (`cmd+F`) should come up with the same results, as "About This Mac > Storage" did.

In the search criteria set "Kind is Movie", click the plus sign towards the right of this line and add another two criteria (found under "Other" in the criteria options): "System Files are included" and for good measure "File Visibility Visible or Invisible".

[image: Spotlight criteria used]

Here these search results show the same amount of space used as given under "Storage" in "About this Mac".